# UWP Windows syncing notifications with action center

Tags: push-notification, windows-10, uwp

Is there any way we can sync notifications with action center in Windows 10? Below is the scenario:

The Windows 10 UWP application I am building has the UI to see all the notifications user is receiving to the app. (I am using the background task to listen to raw notifications and saving to local xml file and show it in the app UI). Now, the requirement is there are many options to user to dismiss the notification. Means, From action center:

1. By clicking the x icon on individual notification.
2. By clicking on App title directly.
3. By clicking "clear" next to App Title.
4. By clicking "Clear All" on top of action center.

In either of the above cases, I need to delete the notifications from the App UI I am building as well. Can anyone help Windows 10 SDK has the support for listening to it when app is either in foreground running or not?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read Notifications History with

```
var history = ToastNotificationManager.History.GetHistory();
```

and compare with your app's data. If notifications are dismissed from action center, then you cannot find them in the history, so you could delete them also from your app.